# "We're sorry, we couldn't find the question you requested." - iOS bug

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm getting this screen every time I post a question on the iOS app and try to view it.

[image]

For example:

[image]

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: (The proposed duplicate is about the Android app, but the cause (API caches too aggressively) is the same.)